# Does the filesystem of a network storage device matter for OS compatibility? (Beginner Question)

Tags: linux, filesystems, file-sharing, nas

I've been using Linux for several years so I'm familiar with the command line, but networking is a mysterious and intimidating thing to me.

When I want to share files between devices I use flash drives or external SSDs/HDDs, and I need to use NTFS or FAT sometimes for compatibility.

I've heard of NAS before, and I thought it could be a way to share files between my Linux installs (using ext4), but after looking into it I'm getting the impression that NAS isn't seen by the OS as a disk, just as "files".  It also seems like the term NAS is kind of a shortcut people use to describe many different things.

So, does the filesystem of the NAS matter in terms of compatibility? (ex: can I use an ext4 formatted NAS drive with Windows?)
Also, am I correct in understanding that NAS is a kind of protocol, or intermediate layer, that an OS communicates with instead of the underlying filesystem?

Comment: Your understanding is flawed. NAS, Network Attached Storage, is a node on your local network that provides access to disk space via filesystem sharing tools like "samba" an "NFS". Clients don't need to know about the NAS's underlying  filesystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NAS = *Network Attached Storage* is a *high-level abstract classification* of a network host dedicated to providing a file-based storage service, using one or more network protocols designed for filesharing (e.g. SMB = Windows filesharing protocol, NFS, the old deprecated Apple-specific AFP, or others).

The filesharing protocol used will hide the NAS host implementation details (like the actual filesystem type used) from the clients, although if a particularly feature-limited filesystem type is used, it may limit the filesharing protocol features the NAS can offer.

For example, if a filesystem that cannot use ACLs (like FAT32 or exFAT) is used on the NAS, then the clients won't typically be able to adjust the access permissions of individual files and directories, as the NAS would have no way of storing the ACLs in such a filesystem in an efficient way. Share-based access permissions would still expected to be controllable, but all files and all directories in any given share would then have the same access permissions as that share has in general.

A system in a NAS role could be a general-purpose computer running a dedicated NAS server OS/software package (such as [FreeNAS/TrueNAS](https://www.truenas.com/freenas/)), or a hardware device designed specifically to provide NAS services (such as the main product line of NetApp Inc.), or even a fault-tolerant arrangement of several such units.

A general-purpose computer running a general-purpose operating system is not typically called a NAS even though it might be configured for the same task: such systems are more commonly described as *file servers* instead. However, as home/small-business NAS appliances can have a lot of ancillary features, this distinction can be somewhat fuzzy.

If the storage is not accessed by file-based requests, but by block-based ones (i.e. instead of "write this data to file named XXX.dat after file position Y", the storage access protocol says things like "write this 16kB block of data starting from block #NNNNNNNNNN of logical disk #ZZZ"), then the applicable high-level classification is not NAS, but *Storage Area Networking* or SAN.

With SAN, the client device will need to understand the actual filesystem format used on the storage - but the storage device won't have to, as it only provides access to raw areas of disk-like storage space.

With modern converged network architectures, SAN access protocols might use regular Ethernet networking, like iSCSI or FCoE (Fibre Channel over Ethernet), or hardware solutions optimized specifically for use with storage, like FibreChannel networking with FCP or FC-NVMe protocols.

While small NAS devices are not uncommon in home/small-business use, SAN solutions are almost exclusively large enterprise things.